# Showing me the code instead of actually running it

Tags: javascript, web, client, server

Please help me, I'm rather new to all of this and I was just wondering how I would be able to submit this data to my simple JavaScript file, which would then execute some commands. Here it is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <center><h1>Test-Page</h1></center>
    <title>Hardware Compare</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="text/javascript">
function updateInput() {
var userIDInput = document.getElementById('userID');
var submittedInput = userIDInput.value;
document.getElementById('testingID').innerHTML='submittedInput'
}
</script>
    <div class="testing">
    <h2 id="testingID">Sign In</h2>
    <form name="input" action="login.js" method="POST">
        Username: <input type="text" name="userID" />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sub" />
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

and here is the javascript code:

```
function updateInput() {
var userIDInput = document.getElementsByName("UserID")[0].value;
var submittedInput = userIDInput.value;
document.getElementById('testingID').innerHTML=submittedInput
```

}

The roblem is that on submit, the web browser displays the actual code instead of running it :/ This has had me troubled for some time now and I can't seem to fix it. It's probably some common noob mistake but I would really appreciate some help, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form is submitted to server side script in PHP, Ruby, NodeJS, Python, etc. You can't submit to another javascript file like your are trying to.

However looks like you need form `onsubmit` event. In this case HTML will be:

```
<form name="input" onsubmit="return updateInput();" method="POST">
    Username: <input type="text" name="userID" />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sub" />
</form>
```

and then `updateInput` function would handle this event and do whatever you want it to do:

```
function updateInput() {
    var userIDInput = document.getElementsByName("userID")[0];
    var submittedInput = userIDInput.value;
    document.getElementById('testingID').innerHTML = submittedInput;
    return false;
}
```

Also note, that you have two mistakes in `updateInput` function. There input name is `userID` and you need to remove `.value` from `userIDInput`.